# Adding parameter to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

In PHP, I can bind a variable to a lambda like this:

```
$locale = "nl_NL";
$info['t'] = function($text, $render) use ($locale) {
   return translate($text, $locale);
}
```

In the below code, the `fullpath` variable gets overwritten and contains the value of the latest call at some point.

```
var tree = {
    "foo.js": null,
    "bar.js": {
         "baz.js": null
    }
}

loadScriptTree(tree) {
    for (let idx in tree) {
        var fullpath = "root/" + idx;
        console.log("Loading "+fullpath);

        var subtree = tree[idx];            
        $.getScript(fullpath, function() {
            console.log(fullpath+ "loaded.");
            loadScriptTree(subtree);
        });
    }
}
```

How can I bind the variable to the function in JavaScript?

Comment: There's a `bind` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`

Comment: `root` doesn't look like it's defined?

Comment: @zer00ne it is defined. I'll update the question.

Comment: @CodeManiac that was it, I changed `var fullpath` into `let fullpath` and it works as expected now. Thanks.